# Need Hibernate Restrictions that is always false

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate 5.1.17.  What I need is a Restrictions object that is always false.  I know I can make a situationally-specific Restriction, but I am looking for a general solution (something like 1=2).  I need this because I am later joining a number of Restrictions with an OR.  If I am not interested in a particular element of the OR condition, I just want it always to be false.  Is there a generic way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I use something like `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1 <> 1")` in my previous project

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `criterion` API of HBN, however I did believe it shares the same ideas  with `Criteria` API like `CriteriaBuilder.or()` is [always false expression](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/criteria/internal/predicate/CompoundPredicate.java#L149), unfortunately it does not, and in case of `criterion` API "always false expression" is `Restrctions.not(Restrictions.or())` or `Restrctions.not(Restrictions.and())` (please check [Junction implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/Junction.java#L77)).

So, taking into account different semantics of `CriteriaBuilder.or()` and `Restrictions.or()` and the fact that `criterion` API has been deprecated in HBN5 and removed in HBN6 I would suggest you to either stay with `1=2` or use `Restrctions.not(Restrictions.and())`